# How to retrieve SF actor service name programmatically?

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the DefaultService Name attribute from ServiceManifest.xml inside other services? Example: actor's service name inside a Web API service. I am trying to avoid hard-coding anything.

Comment: If you're worried about hard coding it you could always make it a value inside of your Config package. If it needs to change then you can update the Config package with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to avoid hard-coding of application type name and other things but you can try something like this in your controller

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<srting> Get(int id)
{
    var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
    string applicationTypeName = "ApplicationTypeName";
    string applicationVersion = "1.0.0";
    string actorServiceManifestName = "Actor1Pkg";
    var appManifest = await fabricClient.ServiceManager.GetServiceManifestAsync(applicationTypeName, applicationVersion, actorServiceManifestName);

    var document = XDocument.Parse(appManifest);
    ...
    // TODO: Get DefaultService Name attribute from simple XML
}
```

You will get an xml, then find the desired attribute